# May I know how to find the value of $a$ that satisfies all the conditions given

Tags: systems-of-equations, solution-verification

I am doing this question:
For simultaneous equations:
$$ ax - y + z =3$$
$$2ax - y + 3z=7$$
$$3ax - y +5z = b$$
Find a value of 'a' such that there exists a solution for which $x>10^6$, and $ y^2 + z^2 <1$, and the value of b is arbitrary.
In this case, what I do is to set $b=11 $ ,$a \neq 0$. So that the value  z can be any thing. Since the question only asks for a solution, could we set the values of z and y be 0. So that we could get$$ ax=3$$Thus, $$\frac{3}{a}>10^6$$ $$a<\frac{3}{10^6}$$. Then, we just pick a value of a between 0 and $\frac{3}{10^6}$. May I know whether my working is right, and is there any good way to do this question.
Thank you very much users.

Comment: If you set $y=z=0$ notice that you get $ax = 3, 2ax = 7$ which has no solutions. But otherwise, your approach of finding a set of solutions and then setting $a$ to be a fraction of its original value, will work.

Comment: Let $u = ax$ and solve for $u, y, z$. You will find that $y = z = 0$ is not an option. But there are other options for $y, z$ that will work. Choose one, find the corresponding value of $u$, then choose $a$ as you did above so that $x = \frac ua > 10^6$